# What is the download location for Ubuntu 9.10 64bit for Intel i7 processors

Tags: 64-bit, ubuntu-9.10, vmware-workstation

When I go to the ubuntu website - it says the ISO is for AMD 64. I have intel 64-bit. I tried this page : http://www.ubuntu.com/GetUbuntu/download  - and selected 64-bit - the downloaded ISO had "amd64" in its name.

Additionally I have vmWare workstation 7.0 (latest version) running on Windows 7 64-bit (I7 Dell XPS Studio).

Is 64-bit Ubuntu virtual machine under VMWARE supposed to work well with this setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to elaborate on Ivo's answer:

AMD64 or X86_64 are identical and all 64bit x86 architecture cpus will work with these, which is to say: all the AMD or INTEL cpus EXCEPT the Itanium line from Intel. Those fall into the IA64 architecture.... but they're almost unrepresented in most business hardare and completely absent in consumer grade equipment.

So all the Xeons, Core Duos, Core2s, I5s and i7s are AMD/x86_64.

Why you ask? AMD "created" and added the 64bit extensions to the 32bit X86 architecture. Intel didn't. Intel added them *after* AMDs cpus proved very popular. Most people now agnostically refer to this as x86_64, but some still call it amd64.

Comment: And Microsoft call it x64. Four names for the same architecture, just to confuse everyone nicely, hooray.

Answer (score 2):

I think just selecting the 64 bit version is enough

There shouldn't be a difference between AMD or Intel processors

[As for VMware support:](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws7/doc/releasenotes_ws701.html) New Support for 32-Bit and 64-Bit Operating Systems

This release provides support for the following host and guest operating systems:

- Windows 2008 R2
- Windows Vista SP2
- Ubuntu 9.10